# Comparing hundreds of JPEG images taken from multiple angles

Tags: python, jpeg

I am comparing X-ray images to find a specific difference between these images. All images are in jpeg format. Sometimes there are six, or eight different camera angles from which these images are taken. From each angle there are ~ 100 images. I am trying to compare a couple of hundred images to identify a specific difference between these images.

I am using Python and I am relatively new to it. Can Sci-kit image segmentation be used for the following problems?

1. Compensate for the image exposure variations in all images
2. Compensate for image size variations in all images

Comment: Typo. Yes, I meant "different camera angles"

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Sci-kit, but I'm sure [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/index.html) can do the job!

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV
- http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/exposure_compensation.html
- http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html

Comment: Thanks Laurent. I reviewed the pages you suggested. Seems like most of them are recommended for coding done in C++. I have to use Python for this project, hence I'm looking for help on Python. Thanks for the suggestion though, OpenCV has some really useful information.

Comment: Yes, with Python, you can use an OpenCV wrapper, for instance: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python/3.1.0.3

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using Anaconda which has OpenCV package pre-installed. Can I use this wrapper to write code in Python?